# learning rate effetcs on model training

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model for a simple classification task (cats or dogs). The model wouldn't learn (validation loss was 0.5 for all the epochs) when the learning rate was 0.005. I changed that learning rate to 0.001 and the model started to learn (validation loss started to decrease and it converged at 24th epoch). Any ideas why changing the learning rate caused this difference?

Comment: This is a *huge* and very general issue, not exactly appropriate for an SO question. Anyway, for starters, have a look at the relevant section of the [Stanford CS231n course](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#loss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The learning rate represents (in simple words) how fast your model will change the features it thinks are important to identify a sample. So, if your learning rate is too high it may change these key features too often and not learn at all, because it gave up on an important feature because the learning rate is too high and it told the model to move to other feature. In your case your learning rate was too high.

It normally has a start value, but it comes with a decreasing function that, as the learning process moves forward it will decrease the learning rate so you should check that too, if your learning rate is stuck at some value. Because of all that the learning rate is a parameter of your network optimization that needs tuning to be optimal.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) article on Stochastic Gradient Descent shows where mathematically the learning rate goes in the whole optimization process, you should check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Do you think 0.005 is too big when compared to 0.001 to bring about such a huge difference in the network training?

Comment: If you take into consideration that normally you'd set the step function of the learning rate to 0.1, you'd see that that is a big difference, this means that at every x (a pre-determined number of) epochs you'd decrease the learning rate to 10% of its value. But at the end of the day it all depends on your problem. For example, just last month I was training a network with a base learning rate of 0.005 and it was just fine.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Do you have any idea on what factors influence the choice of learning rate (like training data size etc. ) ?

Comment: I can't answer that question :/ All I know is that you'd start with a certain value and sometimes do cross validation to try and see if it works for other values until you find one that works for you. As this is a hyper-parameter it needs tuning :/

Comment: Thankyou so much.